# Dynamic email list using sql table for recipient

Tags: c#

I'm looking to send multiple emails from a c# console app using a sql table column as the source for my list.

With the following code i'm getting an error "System.FormatException: 'The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address.'"

When I send the output to console all that is passing to  var m is the first letter of the string.

I'm very close to having this work as this looks like the last piece.

Could anyone please point me in the direction to get this to work.

```
        con = new SqlConnection("MyConnectionString");

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM UserEmails";
        cmd.Connection = con;

        try
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {

                MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();

                //string[] to = { "me@hotmail.com", "me@gmail.com"}; //<-- this works 

                string to = reader.GetString(1);   //<-- this dosent work :( 

                foreach (var m in to)
                {
                    mailMessage.To.Add(m);
                }

                mailMessage.Subject = "Hello";
                mailMessage.Body = "This is a test email";
                mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("me@gmail.com", "me");

                SmtpClient smtpMail = new SmtpClient();
                smtpMail.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                smtpMail.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("me@gmail.com", "password");
                smtpMail.EnableSsl = true;

                try
                {
                    smtpMail.Send(mailMessage);
                    Console.WriteLine("Message Sent");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString());
                }
            }
            reader.Close();
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
```

Comment: What does `reader.GetString(1)` contain? What does your debugger tell you?

Comment: @mxmissile, It contains the full email address. it's when it goes to var m that it becomes 1 character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your iterating through the characters of `to`, which is a string.

Instead of this:

```
foreach (var m in to)
{
  mailMessage.To.Add(m);
}
```

Do this:

```
mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(to));
```